# Good practice on file placement

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jxl

I am developping a web-app which is generating Excel files at some point, using the JXL API.

I was considering placing these files in the `WebContent` folder (into two subfalders, namely template and temp, differing on their nature) but it occured to me that no file produced was of the web content type.

They are not to be accessed by the user at any time (for, say, downloading), and this is not gonna be the case in any foreseeable future (and not "as is" anyway, so they wouldn't be web content either)

What is the best practice then to place these files, considering that any file placed into the temp subfolder are application-generated and the ones placed in the templates subfolder are not to be modified, except for application maintenance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not put them anywhere in the web application folder structure, especially if they're not going to be directly accessible. Rather dedicate an area on the server for the files and then control all the access to the files through your web application.

Another option is to always generate the files on the fly, and rely on caching to serve the files efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. Yes they will be generated on the fly from the templates, as well as destructed on the fly too.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to place it anywhere you want as soon as it's outside the web root.
If in the future you need to access those files you can still write some code to render it to the user, adding an eventual access check to it.